# Accept multiple optional params in C# method for ASP.NET DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net, methods, code-behind

i have a web form with a 5 of asp.net dropdownlist on. I would like to have a method in the code behind that allows me to pass in the name of the dropdownlist and disables it. I have the following code which works but i think it could be written cleaner allowing me to disable more than one dropdownlist when calling the method once, as opposed to currently where if i want to disable two or three i must call the method three times each time passing the different names of the dropdownlist.  i hope the code below makes it a bit clearer:

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        disableDropDown(DropDownList1);
    }


    protected DropDownList disableDropDown(DropDownList a)
    {
        if (a != null)
        {
            a.Enabled = false;
            return a;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }


}
```

Would it be better to have something like disableDropDown(DropDownList1, DropDownList2);
for example if i wanted to disable two boxes, instead of having to call the same method twice with different dropdownlists? If so, how would my actual "disableDropDown" function be modified to allow more than one dropdownlist?

Many thanks

Comment: Why do you return the `DropDownList`?

Comment: i suppose you dont need to, maybe function just to disable them which accepts multiple dropdownlists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way, you could use a [`params`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx) array:

```
public static void EnableControls(bool enable, params WebControl[] controls)
{
    foreach (WebControl c in controls)
    {
        if (c != null) c.Enabled = enable;
    }
}
```

Note that

- I return `void`(nothing) since you just set a property of already available controls. Returning them would be pointless
- I have added a parameter `enable` which allows to enable or disable the controls
- I have changed it to acceppt `WebControls` since that's the class with the `Enabled` property, on this way you can use it for other controls like `TextBox` or `Label` as well, so your method is more useful
- `public static` makes it also more usable, you don't need to access the instance of the surrounding `Page`-class anyway.

You can call it with single `DropDownList`s:

```
EnableControls(false, dropdown1, dropdown2, dropdown3);
```

or with an array (pseudo code):

```
var manyDropDowns = new DropDownList[]{ dropdown1, ..., dropDown999999 };
EnableControls(false, manyDropDowns);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `params`. (Also, you don't need to return anything from here.)

```
protected void DisableDropDown(params DropDownList[] ddls)
{
    foreach(var ddl in ddls)
    {
        ddl.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

And use it like so:

```
DisableDropDown(DropDownList1, DropDownList2, DropDownList3);
```